# Can we use "only" instead of "rules" in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

In my gitlab ci/cd script , we are using rules

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "developer" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"|| ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "developer" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "stage"|| ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
      when: never
```

for specific job , we are using only

```
only:
  - developer
  - stage
```

FINE. but I want the scenerio like

```
only:
  - developer
  - stage
  - (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
```

the sprint which I used is not working . If I use "**rules**" , its working , but I want "**only**" to be used in my script . Please help me to sort it out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`only:` directove](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) does support [regular expressions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#only--except-regex-syntax) that match against branch names.

But the syntax is like `/^feature-.*/`, so check if the outer `()` are in the way.

Plus, there seems to be an imbalance in the 5 `(`  vs. 6 `)`.

So either:

```
 (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i)
```

Or

```
 /^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216766/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array-issue-facing-in-ku?noredirect=1#comment127596994_72216766 please help me to sort this out

Comment: @CyrilI Didn't sytech's comment already answered the question?

Comment: @sytech just ask me , this is related to this problem or not! .Please look in to that issue. If you have an idea, Please help me to sort it out this